# colcon build - number of threads

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How Can I define the number of threads for a colcon building process in ROS2?

In previous ros building tools we used "-j {number_of_threads}", but that does not work anymore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368249/colcon-build---number-of-threads/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-12-22

Post score: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two independent dimensions of parallelization:

- The maximum number of packages processed in parallel when using the [parallel executor](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-parallel-executor). This dimension can be limited with the option `--parallel-workers NUMBER`. It can also be limited to 1 by selecting the sequential executor with `--executor sequential`.
- The maximum number of threads used for a specific package using `make`. This can be controlled using the environment variable [MAKEFLAGS](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html). By setting e.g. `export MAKEFLAGS="-j 4"` only four threads are used to build a single package. By default [colcon-cmake](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake) uses the number of available CPU cores (including hyper threading) to limit the number of threads (`-j`) as well as the system load (`-l`).

As a result the overall number of threads is the product of packages processed in parallel and maximum number of threads per package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brianlmerritt](https://answers.ros.org/users/78477/brianlmerritt/) on 2021-11-10**:
For anyone finding this, I found that colcon build on a Raspberry Pi 4 can crash, but adding --executor sequential sorted this out without a massive time penalty.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`--parallel-workers NUMBER` is the syntax you're looking for. "-j N" is a make specific argument.

There's documentation of the parallel executor command line options here: https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/executor-arguments.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score -1):

yes, `export MAKEFLAGS="-j 1"` can fix this error:

```sh
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
```